# WooCommerce - Display Price Without Tax on Product Page

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am using WooCommerce & WooShop Theme for Wordpress.

I need to display the Product Price EXCLUDING tax on Single Product Page.

There are 2 functions if I understand correctly:

**$_product->get_price()

$_product->get_price_excluding_tax()**

*and this is **Price.php** (Under Single Product)*

```
<p itemprop="price" class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
```

which leads to

```
  'price_html' => '<span class="price">'.$variation->get_price_html().'</span>',
```

Any ideas?

**THANKS!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this question is old, but here's a go for anyone else looking for an answer to using those functions in the proper way.

I found that when I used `$_product->get_price_excluding_tax()` it would return the full price.

However, after adjusting a setting in WooCommerce, it now appears correctly.

You should tick the box the says **"Catalog prices defined including tax"**.

[image: Tax setting]

You also need to make sure that you have a tax rule setup in the 'Tax' tab. I setup one for UK VAT at 20%.

[image: Tax creation]

Hope that this helps somebody in future.

Thanks,
Mikey.